# I have updated my android sdk but now avd is not running

Tags: android

I have updated my android sdk but now avd is not running and eclipse is giving me the following error.

```
[2011-10-30 01:22:18 - Lecture04] Android Launch!
[2011-10-30 01:22:18 - Lecture04] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-30 01:22:18 - Lecture04] Performing com.pucit.lecture04.First activity launch
[2011-10-30 01:22:18 - Lecture04] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'First'
[2011-10-30 01:22:18 - Lecture04] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'First'
[2011-10-30 01:22:19 - Lecture04] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-10-30 01:22:19 - Lecture04] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-10-30 01:23:40 - Lecture04] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'lecture04.First activity launch'!
```

Now what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Saw similar after upgrading Google tools to v14. Not sure what's the matter, but killing the ADB process and restarting the relevant ADB *not* from snapshot helped.